# MSAccess Insert with sub select wont work

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have simple query, but when I'm trying to execute this query I'm getting error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query. (Error 3067)

Query:

```
INSERT INTO FV_Ko ( FvId, OldPriceNetto )
SELECT [PFvId], (SELECT FV.PriceNetto1 FROM FV WHERE FV.FVnr = '123');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PFvld is a parameter and the query (MyQuery) is saved (part of the MSAccess database), then you should be able to do:

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
qdf.Parameters("[PFvld]") = myValue
```

If you compose the query on the fly and execute it, then you might just specify a value when composing the SQL code instead of a parameter (not that it is a better solution though).

Comment: Its not true, becasue when I'm executing that querry in that way Im getting error. The same when Im opening querry from Access.

Comment: when you have a query with a parameter and you open it directly in MSAccess (double-click or menu "Open"), it should bring little dialog box asking you to enter the parameter. Does it? If it does not, then MSAccess does not think it is a parameter, but rather some field etc. But DJ's answer is also the correct way to compose the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

This should work - it should ask you for [PFvId]

```
INSERT INTO FV_Ko ( FvId, OldPriceNetto ) 
SELECT [PFvId], FV.PriceNetto1 FROM FV WHERE FV.FVnr = '123';
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is OK, but you aren't saying where PFvID is coming from. Your INSERT should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO FV_Ko ( FvId, OldPriceNetto ) 
SELECT AnotherTable.PFvId, 
(SELECT FV.PriceNetto1 FROM FV WHERE FV.FVnr = '123') FROM AnotherTable
```

Comment: [PFvId] is a parameter passed from VBA script, not from another table: that's the problem. Any ideas how to pass parameters for that querry?

Answer (score 0):

```
...   
SELECT [PFvId], --> you should define a FROM table at end of the query
(SELECT FV.PriceNetto1 FROM FV WHERE FV.FVnr = '123');
```